# How do I do unique keyword simplification and sort alphabetically on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
id  keyword
1   transfer atm transfer atm
2   transfer transfer atm
3   atm transfer hospital
```

Here's what I want is sort keyword alphabetically and make this unique, based on alphabetical the word on `keyword` after sort alphabetically is `atm`, `hospital`, and `transfer`

```
id  keyword
1   atm transfer
2   atm transfer
3   atm hospital transfer
```

Comment: Nice question.  By the way, remember that if there are uppercase and lowercase letters, you may get unexpected results when sorting.  Don't forget to test the result if you have lower and uppercase to check you are getting what you expect.

Comment: @jberrio I am already using str.lower on previous cleansing steps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['keyword']=df['keyword'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(sorted(set(x.split()))))
```

O/P:

```
   id                keyword
0   1           atm transfer
1   2           atm transfer
2   3  atm hospital transfer
```

Explanation:

1. split the words by white space.
2. find the common words i.e., remove repeated words.
3. sort the selected words

Answer (score 5):

Idea is to split values by whitespace, convert to sets, sort and join with whitespace:

```
df['keyword'] = [' '.join(sorted(set(x.split()))) for x in df['keyword']]
#apply alternative
#df['keyword'] = df['keyword'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(set(x.split()))))
print (df)
   id                keyword
0   1           atm transfer
1   2           atm transfer
2   3  atm hospital transfer
```